# DB performance very slow

Tags: sql

the following procedure

dt_addtosourcecontrol, dt_addtosourcecontrol_u, dt_adduserobject

are formed in one of the server DB named DB1 , whereas we have  two other DB with same DB structure as DB1 with some what less data but in them above said procedure are not there.

here the first said DB, DB1 with some extra  procedure like

dt_addtosourcecontrol, dt_addtosourcecontrol_u, dt_adduserobject

is very slow when connected to our application, whereas others are fine.

Does the above xtra procedure is the reason for the slow?

is their any way to improve the speed of the DB or check its performance?

Comment: You should document which DBMS you're using.  The problem is not the stored procedures, but something else.  Are 'statistics' relevant to your DBMS?  Are they up to date?

Comment: I've recently written a blog post explaining various ways to debug SQL Server performance issues. This may be of help to debug this. http://www.redant.com/articles/design-and-build/sql-server-performance-troubleshooting-for-dummies/

Answer (score 1):

No, the existance of some stored procedures doesn't affect the performance of a database.

Check that the databases also have the same indexes defined. There might be a slight difference in performance between databases if the data differs somewhat, but barely enough to be noticable. If an index is missing, it can make a big difference in performance.

Answer (score 0):

If this is an MS SQL Server use [SQL Profiler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181091.aspx) to find the slow performing queries (or other actions on the DB)